What is the reason of the error Cannot create permission set group components since the following permission set names are invalid:
During our CI/CD Development pipeline one particular error is reoccuring every time pipeline is invoked

Cannot create permission set group components since the following
permission set names are invalid:

following an empty space, so it doesn't really provide any details about which permission set names are actually invalid.
We assumed first this to be some intermittent failure that would disappear and go away but it didn't disappear and neither went away. What is this and how this can be fixed or avoided?

Opened a SF Support Case and they told me that this particular error may happen in three following cases:

duplicated permission set name in psg xml
muting permission set in psg xml
Different namespaces in psg (known issue is available for this particular case:  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zHrsw/deploying-permission-set-group-is-failing-when-the-permission-set-group-contains-the-two-different-namespace-managed-package-permission-sets-with-same)

In our case we had the same permission set name duplicated because of bad merge conflict resolution.
